# Xcode Theme - not a directory when creating a folder

Tags: xcode, unix, terminal, xcode6

I am trying to install Xcode themes from https://github.com/hdoria/xcode-themes as from their instructions at the bottom. I am attempting to create a directory. However it keeps telling me that it's not a directory. This is what I'm trying to do...

```
08:15 PM - cd 

08:20 PM - ls
Applications/ Documents/    Dropbox/      Movies/       OneDrive/     Public/
Desktop/      Downloads/    Library/      Music/        Pictures/

08:20 PM - mkdir ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/
mkdir: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData: Not a directory

08:20 PM - mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/
mkdir: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/: Not a directory
```

Comment: Well i was one link away from the solution in a Google search. The most straight forward way is to look for directory under Finder >> Go >> Go To Folder and search the directory. If no directory exists manually create the folders in Finder. I'm still curious to know why it didn't work via the Terminal.

Comment: that's very strange - the mkdir worked fine for me, and your error message `Not a directory` seems to be saying that `UserData` exists, but is a plain file instead of a directory, which doesn't make sense. If you do `ls -ld ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData` does it look like a normal directory?

Comment: Bash can get funny ideas sometimes. One of them is the state of various files, where it can insist it knows about a thing that's patently wrong. That's because it's caching the file state, as if it's the only thing in the world looking at that file. You can get it to give up its idea by running "hash -r" in the shell instance in question, or killing the instance and starting a new one. Dunno if this applies here, but it's my best guess.

Comment: @CupawnTae it does list folders/files when i type ls -ld ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData

Comment: @Beast_Code well it should only list one when you run that command - `-ld` tells it to list the details of a directory instead of the contents of that directory, so you should only get details for `UserData`. And it's those details I was interested in - e.g. is it s symbolic link? (not that that should cause the issue, but that kind of thing)...

Comment: @CupawnTae $ ls -ld ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData
drwxr-xr-x  7 username  staff   238B Feb 28 20:40 /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/

Comment: Looks normal enough. Kinda stumped. @HackSaw's idea is interesting, but `mkdir` is a separate binary as opposed to a bash built-in so I don't *think* it should apply... And I presume you don't have `mkdir` aliased to anything else? Does it still happen? i.e. if you try `mkdir ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/DeleteMe` do you get the same error?